# Cannot connect to SQL Server on docker from .NET Core API project with docker support enabled

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, docker

There was an error when I'm want to connect sql server at docker from my dotnet core api project with docker support.
But outside the project, I can connect to server with ssms(SQL Server Management Studio).
Before this, I was able to connect to my localdb from projects with no docker support.
But Now when I want to use localdb as my docker support enabled project development SQL server, I got the error "Localdb not supported in containered application", for this ,I'm installed the mssql docker version to my docker engine.
I Can connect to server with ssms,but I got error "A Network Related Error was Occurred" Inside the Project.
AnyOne can help me,Please let me how to solve this.

I was tryed to change the connection string Data Source to localhost,1433,but no chance.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78145975/edit) your question with enough information that somebody could provide an answer. Where is your SQL Server instance installed? Is it installed and running on the Docker host itself, or is it a version of `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` running in a Docker container? If it's in a Docker container what port/s did you publish it with? Where is your API project running? Is it also running on the Docker host? Is it running inside a Dev Container in VS Code or another Docker container? What connection string does it use? Code? Error messages?